# S3 download is too slow when concurrent instance download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a system that processes big data sets and downloads data from an S3 bucket.

Each instance downloads multiple objects from inside an object (dir) on S3. When the number of instances are less, the download speeds are good *i.e.* `4-8MiB/s`.
But when I use like `100-300` instances the download speed reduce to `80KiB/s`.

Wondering what might be the reasons behind it and what ways can I use to remedy it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are the objects in your S3 bucket named? The naming of the objects can have a surprisingly large effect on the throughput of the bucket due to partitioning. In the background, S3 partitions your bucket based on the keys of the objects, but only the first 3-4 characters of the key are really important. Also note that the key is the entire path in the bucket, but the subpaths don't matter for partitioning. So if you have a bucket called `mybucket` and you have objects inside like `2017/july/22.log`, `2017/july/23.log`, `2017/june/1.log`, `2017/oct/23.log` then the fact that you've partitioned by month doesn't actually matter because only the first few characters of the *entire* key are used.

If you have a sequential naming structure for the objects in your bucket, then you will likely have bad performance with many parallel requests for objects. In order to get around this, you should assign a random prefix of 3-4 characters to each object in the bucket.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html for more information.

Comment: This is a misapplication of the concept you're referencing, which is only relevant with regard to index actions.  The index is what is partitioned, and those partitions are what the service can split in order to accommodate higher *request rates* (not faster transfers). The objects are stored separately.  This should not have any impact on bandwidth throughput.

Comment: I wrote a quick script to rename all sequential files with 5 random char in front and could instantly see download speeds not only 100x better but also consistent. Thank you so much @Brian Ecker

Comment: @AyushKSingh, glad it helped.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, if you assume that there is some sort of partitioned storage in the backend of S3, then it makes perfect sense that each partition would provide a certain amount of finite bandwidth, doesn't it? Why would only the "index" be partitioned? Surely the underlying storage isn't on one mega machine, which means that it is effectively partitioned across multiple machines in some way.

Comment: @BrianEcker very true, but not partitioned by object key.  It could be partitioned by content hash or random numbers or just about anything, and as such would be infinitely more scalable than a lexical index.

Answer (score 8):

If your EC2 instances are in **private subnets**, then your NAT may be a limiting factor.

Try the following:

- Add S3 endpoints to your VPC. This bypasses your NAT when your EC2 instances talk to S3.
- If you are using NAT instances, try using NAT gateways instead. They can scale up/down the bandwidth.
- If you are using a NAT instance, try increasing the instance type of your NAT instance to one with more CPU and Enhanced Networking.
- If you are using a single NAT, try using multiple NATs instead (one per subnet). This will spread the bandwidth across multiple NATs.
- If all that fails, try putting your EC2 instances into public subnets.

Comment: Or use replace NAT instances with one or more NAT Gateways (~10 Gbit/s burst, each).

Comment: S3 endpoint is probably the best of these, but all good suggestions (although cost of a NAT Gateway can be prohibitive).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [S3DistCP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) instead of managing concurrency and connections by hand...